# How to make procedure with timestamp typedata

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have tried to make a procedure on PLSQL.
The proble is "ORA-01843: not a valid month" when i to execute code as bellow..
My problem on TIMESTAMP

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_InsertOvertimes
(
ov_id IN VARCHAR,
dro_id IN DATE,
sto_id IN TIMESTAMP,
eto_id IN TIMESTAMP,
acto_id IN Varchar,
otfk_id IN VARCHAR,
slfk_id IN VARCHAR,
SttsO_id IN VARCHAR,
empfk_id IN NUMBER
)
IS
BEGIN
  INSERT into TB_T_Overtimes VALUES (ov_id,dro_id,TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(sto_id,'HH24:MI')),eto_id, acto_id,otfk_id,slfk_id,sttso_id,empfk_id);
END;

==== EXECUTE
BEGIN
  SP_InsertOvertimes(9, '07/08/2019','01:12', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'Kerja Lembur Bagai Kuda', '1', '1', 'Kampret' ,1);
END;
```

Comment: Why do you make `TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(sto_id,'HH24:MI'))`? If you like to truncate input data by Minute then better use `TRUNC(sto_id, 'MI')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should match datatypes. Here's an example which shows how you might have done that.

Sample table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE tb_t_overtimes(
  2    ov_id      VARCHAR2(20),
  3    dro_id     DATE,
  4    sto_id     TIMESTAMP,
  5    eto_id     TIMESTAMP,
  6    acto_id    VARCHAR2(20),
  7    otfk_id    VARCHAR2(20),
  8    slfk_id    VARCHAR2(20),
  9    sttso_id   VARCHAR2(20),
 10    empfk_id   NUMBER
 11  );

Table created.
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_insertovertimes(
  2    ov_id      IN         VARCHAR,
  3    dro_id     IN         DATE,
  4    sto_id     IN         TIMESTAMP,
  5    eto_id     IN         TIMESTAMP,
  6    acto_id    IN         VARCHAR,
  7    otfk_id    IN         VARCHAR,
  8    slfk_id    IN         VARCHAR,
  9    sttso_id   IN         VARCHAR,
 10    empfk_id   IN         NUMBER
 11  )IS
 12  BEGIN
 13    INSERT INTO tb_t_overtimes VALUES(
 14      ov_id,
 15      dro_id,
 16      sto_id,
 17      eto_id,
 18      acto_id,
 19      otfk_id,
 20      slfk_id,
 21      sttso_id,
 22      empfk_id
 23    );
 24
 25  END;
 26  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2    sp_insertovertimes
  3      ('9',
  4       DATE '2019-08-07',
  5       to_timestamp('01:12', 'hh24:mi'),
  6       current_timestamp,
  7       'Kerja Lembur',
  8       '1',
  9       '1',
 10       'Kampret',
 11       1);
 12  END;
 13  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From tb_t_overtimes;

OV_ID                DRO_ID
-------------------- -------------------
STO_ID
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ETO_ID
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACTO_ID              OTFK_ID              SLFK_ID
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
STTSO_ID               EMPFK_ID
-------------------- ----------
9                    07.08.2019 00:00:00
01.07.19 01:12:00,000000
19.07.19 14:59:08,320000
Kerja Lembur         1                    1
Kampret                       1


SQL>
```

Comment: How can i want to execute with only this code ?

BEGIN
  SP_InsertOvertimes('10','2019-08-07','01:12', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'Kerja Lembur Bagai Kuda', '1', '1', 'Kampret' ,1);
END;

Comment: You'll have to do the conversion within the procedure. Once again, datatypes must match. "'01:12'" is a string, not a timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Input value `'07/08/2019'` is not a `DATE`, it is a string value. Oracle tries implicitly to convert this into a DATE value by using your current session `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` format. Use `TO_DATE` or `TO_TIMESTAMP` function or [Datetime Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062) for example `DATE '2019-08-07'`

According to your input parameters `dro_id IN DATE, sto_id IN TIMESTAMP,` and values `'07/08/2019','01:12'` you probably misunderstand `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` data type.

**Every** `DATE` value has a date and a time component. Even if you provide only the date part, then the time part will be `00:00:00`. There is no reason to have separate columns for data and time value.

`DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` data type are more or less the same. Both data types have date and time component. The major difference is `TIMESTAMP` provides also fractional seconds whereas `DATE` has only full seconds.

Comment: Also TIMESTAMP can have a timezone, unlike DATE

Answer (score 0):

Execute your procedure with the second argument with `date'2019-07-08'` instead of `'07/08/2019'` to remove the error, assuming your month is July.

Moreover, the first parameter should be quoted (`'9'`), because it's defined as `varchar` (*not as numeric*) in the table.